# Assigning TreeNode to TreeView and show as selected

Tags: treeview, treenode, selectedindex

HI,

I have `TreeNode trn` which is containing treenode with some of its child nodes.
Now i want to pass this node to  `TreeView tree`  from another method and i want to the show the `trn` as selected tree node in the `TreeView tree`.

(`trn` is likely to change every time as per the selection by user)

I have tried using

```
tree.SelectedNode = trn;
```

but it is giving me absurd result like sometimes highlighting another node or sometimes highlighting the Root node only etc.

Do we have indexes for treeNode so if  i get index of any node so i will just use

```
tree.SelectedIndex = index;
```

But i am not sure that SelectedIndex  really exists for TreeNode ?

Any help

Regards,

Sangram Nandkhile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one.

```
tree.select();
tree.SelectedNode = trn;
```